# CMake: how to use doxygen_add_docs() for a project with multiple targets and generate during build

Tags: c++, cmake, doxygen

I have a project with the following structure:

```
myproject/
├─ build/
├─ cmake/
│  └─ DoxygenFun.cmake
├─ docs/
├─ src/
│  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
│  ├─ superlib/
│  │  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
│  │  ├─ lib1/
│  │  │  ├─ include/
│  │  │  │  └─ lib1.h
│  │  │  ├─ lib1.cpp
│  │  │  └─ CMakeLists.txt
│  │  └─ lib2/
│  │     ├─ include/
│  │     │  └─ lib2.h
│  │     ├─ lib2.cpp
│  │     └─ CMakeLists.txt
│  └─ exec/
│     ├─ main.cpp
│     ├─ aux.h
│     └─ CMakeLists.txt
└─ CMakeLists.txt
```

`superlib` has two libraries `lib1` and `lib2` defined in CMake with `add_library()`. `lib2` depends on `lib1`. The main executable `exec` (defined with `add_executable()`) depends on `lib2`.

The `CMakeLists.txt` file within `src/` only contains `add_subdirectory()` for `superlib` and `exec`. And the `CMakeLists.txt` file within `src/superlib/` only contains `add_subdirectory()` for `lib1` and `lib2`.

I have a function written in `DoxygenFun.cmake` which gets a target name and its path, sets some `DOXYGEN_` variables and calls `doxygen_add_docs()`. It is:

```
function(DoxygenFun target input)
  set(DOXYGEN_HTML_OUTPUT            ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/docs) # ?????
  set(DOXYGEN_JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      YES)
  set(DOXYGEN_GENERATE_HTML          YES)
  set(DOXYGEN_HAVE_DOT               YES)

# other DOXYGEN_... options

  doxygen_add_docs(doxygen-${target}
      ${input}
      ALL  # add to the default build target
      COMMENT "Generate HTML documentation"
      )
endfunction()
```

My top-level `CMakeLists.txt` is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(myproject VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

find_package(Doxygen REQUIRED dot)
include(DoxygenFun)

add_subdirectory(src bin)

add_custom_target(doc_doxygen ALL
    COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/docs
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}
)
```

Each of the inner `CMakeLists.txt` files associated to the targets have an additional:

```
# ...
DoxygenFun(targetname ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

where `targetname` is the name of the targets I defined for `lib1`, `lib2` or `exec`.

I would like to generate a documentation for the whole project in `{PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/docs` during build. However, my function `DoxygenFun` seems to generate a `Doxyfile` in `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` for each target, instead of a single `Doxyfile` for the whole project inside `{PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/docs`. So then my custom command that runs `${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE}` doesn't do anything.

If I run each generated `Doxyfile` individually from the terminal, it seems that the resulting html files within `{PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/docs` overwrite each other for each target, instead of generating a single html file for the whole project.

Maybe I completely misunderstood how to use `doxygen_add_docs()`? Am I required to glob all source and header files and pass them to only one `doxygen_add_docs()`? What would the target be? I have tried searching for answers in examples online, but they seem to either only do it for projects with a straightforward structure (e.g. [Halide's github repo](https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/doc/CMakeLists.txt)) or not using `doxygen_add_docs()`, which requires some manual configurations with `configure_file()` and (from what I understood) is out-dated.

Also, should there be a `CMakeLists.txt` within `docs/` (and an additional `add_subdirectory(docs)` within the main `CMakeLists.txt` file)?

PS.: I took the `DoxygenFun.cmake` module from the book "Modern CMake for C++" by Rafal Swidzinski. He doesn't show how to make the docs during build, though, only installation.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way to use `doxygen_add_files()` for the whole project.

Firstly, I misunderstood the [documentation of FindDoxygen](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindDoxygen.html). I thought the `targetName` for `doxygen_add_files()` should be for an already existing target. After carefully re-reading, it states that a new target is built with the name `targetName`. I could not find a way to make this new target part of the build. Adding the `ALL` option in `doxygen_add_files()` didn't work. Nevertheless, within CLion the target generated by this function can be run to generate the documentation.

Secondly, in the docs it is written that `RECURSIVE` is set to `YES` in `doxygen_add_files()`. Therefore, you only need to pass the project source directory to `doxygen_add_files()` and doxygen can generate documentation for the whole project. This has the benefit of being able to use a `README.md` file as the main page of the documentation with the variable `DOXYGEN_USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE`.

Note that `DOXYGEN_EXCLUDE_PATTERNS` can be used to exclude a folder, such as `*/extern/*` or `*/deps/*` for a folder containing external dependencies obtained using `FetchContent`, for example.

I have deleted the `DoxygenFun.cmake` file and all usages of the `DoxygenFun` function.

Within `myproject/docs` I added a `CMakeLists.txt` file containing:

```
find_package(Doxygen REQUIRED dot)

set(DOXYGEN_HTML_OUTPUT            ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/docs/html)
set(DOXYGEN_JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      YES)
set(DOXYGEN_GENERATE_HTML          YES)
set(DOXYGEN_HAVE_DOT               YES)
set(DOXYGEN_USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE README.md)  # requires a README.md in /myproject/

# other DOXYGEN_... options

doxygen_add_docs(docs_target
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
  ALL  # does not seem to work
  COMMENT "Generate HTML documentation"
)
```

Then the main `CMakeLists.txt` becomes:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(myproject VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

add_subdirectory(src bin)

add_subdirectory(docs)
```

In CLion I can build `docs_target` to generate the documentation.

I wonder how to run it together with the build...